# Audio not playing through JavaScript when put in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of JavaScript that is supposed to loop through some audio files in series that are defined using audio tags with an id in the HTML body. The problem is that the audio at first would stop in the first 3 seconds, and now it doesn't play at all, and I can't find what's wrong. The below code is all in the HTML body and is the smallest possible example of my error:

```
<audio id="lobby1">
    <source src="audio/lobby-audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="lobby2">
    <source src="audio/lobby-audio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button onclick="playLobby()">play lobby</button>

<script>
    number = 1
    lobbySong = "lobby" + number
    function playLobby() {
        while (number < 2) {
            var lobbySong = document.getElementById(lobbySong);
            lobbySong.play();
            lobbySong.onended = function() {
                number++
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

The error I get from the console is `cannot read property 'play' of null` referring to `lobbySong.play` in the *while* loop.

Comment: code in `while (number < 2) {` will run continuously, not waiting for onended, executing play at an extremely fast pace

Comment: @lucumt - since playlobby is executed via onclick, that won't help and would mean playlobby isn't accessible through onclick

Comment: @JaromandaX ```alert()``` worked ```onclick```

Comment: You are redeclating the variable! lobbySong <--- it has nothing to do with `lobbySong = "lobby" + number`

Comment: how can I make it not go through play at a fast pace? I have tried ```wait(lobbySong.duration*1000);``` without waiting for the ```onended```

Comment: Just because you are increasing `number` doesn't mean you are reassigning `lobbySong` at the top level scope, furthermore such a loop is really pointless.

Comment: yeah, you're right. Solved it with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rewriting the javascript like this

```
function playLobby() {
    let fn = function(number) {
        let lobbySong = "lobby" + number;
        let audio = document.getElementById(lobbySong);
        audio.play();
        audio.onended = function () {
            if (number < 2) {
                fn(number + 1);
            }
        }
    };
    fn(1);
}
```

Comment: thanks. This worked! Is there a way to loop this forever?

Comment: `else { fn(1) }` or `audio.onended = function () { fn(3-number) }`

Comment: I have changed the code a little bit and added it to my join page. However, even with a body onload event triggering the function, it doesn't play again using [this](https://pastebin.com/b36Au3nq) JavaScript in the body and appropriately named audio sources.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the AudioWhore constructor I created:

```js
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, AudioWhore; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
AudioWhore = function(playButton){
  this.stack = [];
  let playing = 0;
  this.add = src=>{
    const a = M('audio');
    a.src = src; this.stack.push(a);
    return this;
  }
  playButton.onclick = ()=>{
    let s = this.stack, l = s.length;
    let p = playing-1 > -1 ? playing-1 : l-1;
    s[p].load();
    if(playing === l)playing = 0;
    s[playing++].play();
  }
}
// magic under here
const ah = new AudioWhore(I('play_button'));
ah.add('http://soundbible.com/mp3/Wind-Mark_DiAngelo-1940285615.mp3').add('http://soundbible.com/mp3/Tornado_Siren_II-Delilah-747233690.mp3');
}); // end load
```

```html
<input id='play_button' type='button' value='play' />
```

Comment: It looks like you would have to hard code every lobby song in there. I mentioned that I have more than 2 songs, but 2 was the smallest example. Am I wrong?